# Text of S'lichos Online

Tags: tefilla, internet, product-recommendation, prayer-book, selichot

Is there any fully digital (i.e. searchable) edition of the סליחות? Is it publicly available online?

Answer (score 7):

Another place to look is [Hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org) (search for סליחות). They've got several editions, some of which have been OCR'ed and are therefore searchable.

Answer (score 7):

Selichot for various eidot can be found at http://daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/shaar-2.htm

Comment: could not see ashkenaz slichot there

Answer (score 5):

Try [this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=cJdLAAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Seder+selihoth+k%CA%BBminhag+Polin+gadol+uFolin+katan&ei=NS-YTNb-LoS8zAT3vtW0CQ&cd=1#v=onepage&q&f=false) to one Selichos edition on Google Books. There is a search box on the left side with which you can find text in that particular edition. Not perfect, but fairly useful. There are probably other editions available there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Sefaria.org has it on different nusachim. Scroll down in liturgy.

Specifically:

- [Edot HaMizrach](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Selichot_Edot_HaMizrach?lang=bi)
- [Nusach Polin](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Selichot_Nusach_Polin%2C_First_Day.1?lang=bi)
- [Nusach Lita](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Selichot_Nusach_Ashkenaz_Lita%2C_First_Day.1?lang=bi)
- [Nusach Lita - Linear English translation](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Linear_Selichot_Nusach_Lita%2C_First_Day.1?lang=bi)